# C++ push_back many 1D vectors in a 2D vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, has-many, push-back

Let's say i have a lot of vectors :

```
vector<int> v1 = ...
vector<int> v2 = ...
...
vector<int> v1000 = ...
```

Is there a quicker way to populate a 2D vector with those 1D vectors than this :

```
vector<vector<int>> vGlobal ;
vGlobal.push_back(v1);
vGlobal.push_back(v2);
.......
VGlobal.push_back(v1000);
```

Comment: Yes, it's called a 'loop', a programming construct that lets you repeat a block of code multiple times.

Comment: @RinatVeliakhmedov The loop is not quicker.

Comment: You could do `std::vector<std::vector<int>> vGlobal{v1, v2, v3};` but _why_ do you have a lot of separate vectors to start with? Why not _only_ have `vGlobal` and index in that? `vGlobal[0]` etc...?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow it is surely quicker than writing a 1000 pushbacks.

Comment: @RinatVeliakhmedov "Yes it's called a loop". Don't know if it's sarcastic but i guess it is...so what would you iterate on ? I'm curious about your reply, please show me your skills

Comment: The dupe is about `int`, but exactly the same thing works for `vector<int>`.

Comment: @Viroun I noticed your deleted answer to this question: "_But this means you have to first populate your vector v with v1,v2,...v1000. Which means pushing back 1000 Times_" - No, what I wrote in my answer creates `1000` vectors so you don't need to `push_back` anything. `v[0]` ... `v[999]` are ready to use directly after `std::vector<std::vector<int>> v(1000);`

Answer (score 1):

It will be faster to

- first reserve 1000 slots and
- then move the vectors into `vGlobal` (iff `v1` to `v1000` aren't needed anymore; if you still need `v1` to be "intact" after the procedure do not use `std::move`)

if you cannot alter the structure.

```
vector<vector<int>> vGlobal;
vGlobal.reserve(1000);
vGlobal.push_back(std::move(v1));
vGlobal.push_back(std::move(v2));
...
VGlobal.push_back(std::move(v1000));
```

If you can alter the structure then I'd advise to use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` to hold all 1000 instances in the first place and not go for `v1`, `v2`, ..., `v1000`.

Answer (score 0):

> Let's say i have a lot of vectors :
>
> ```
> vector<int> v1 = ...
> vector<int> v2 = ...
> ...
> vector<int> v1000 = ...
> ```

Let's pretend that you don't have to manage and name them individually and instead of `v1` to `v1000` you could write `v[0]` to `v[999]` which makes it easy to process all of them in a loop etc?

There are standard solutions for this:

1. If you have a fixed number of these vectors:

   ```
   std::array<std::vector<int>, 1000> v;
   ```
2. If you may want to add/remove vectors in run-time:

   ```
   std::vector<std::vector<int>> v(1000);
   ```

Now, if you for some reason would like to create `vGlobal` with a copy of all the vectors in `v`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vGlobal(v.begin(), v.end());
```